# One Real Solution using Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: calculus

I am uni student learning introductory calculus.

I am struggling with this Intermediate Value Theorem Question

$(x^3-15x^2+74x-112)/(x-2)$.

The equation has at least one real solution. Give an interval on which the Intermediate Value Theorem assures that there is a solution to this equation.

Plotting the graph on Geogebra I thought the answer is (2,3). Considering the line crosses the x axis inbetween those numbers?

What is the correct answer and how do you get to it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The intermediate value theorem implies that if a continuous function is positive in $a$ and negative in $b$, it must be zero somewhere in $(a,b)$. This is what you are supposed to use. So choose an $x$ for which the function is positive, and one where it is negative, and make sure that there are no discontinuities in your chosen interval (this function *does* have one. Where?).

Comment: Note that there are many intervals possible, but the one you gave is wrong, as the function is not defined in $2$. So you couldn't have chosen $2$ as a boundary point where the function is positive/negative.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the thorough explanation.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof You can use $(2+\varepsilon,3)$ and hence bracket the root in $(2,3)$, so it isn't wrong.

Comment: @user10354138 That is not a result you would normally arrive at if you apply the IVT. If I were his teacher evaluating this answer in this context, I'd have problems with this answer unless very properly motivated.